# How to know if a LED power supply will deal correctly with dimming

Tags: power-supply, led, dimming

I have a led strip with its 24V own power supply (IKEA's Ledberg), and I want to make them dimmable. I've successfully done it with an arduino and a MOSFET, but I'm unsure if the power supply will deal with it correctly.

I know that some power supplies will monitor the output and try to provide a constant current, but I'm not sure about the Ledberg ones. Is there any way I can be sure?

Comment: (a) contact IKEA. (b) experiment and see for yourself.

Comment: (a) IKEA will surely just say "you can't". (b) I don't have a problem experimenting. I already did. They dimmed correctly. But I don't know how to check if the power supply will get damaged, without leaving it on/dimmed for a long time (and still, I would not be sure).

Comment: Are the ledbergs holding up being dimmed?

Comment: @JasonLi I haven't done it yet.